# Написать программу, используя операторы цикла

Tags: delphi, алгоритм

Используя операторы цикла, написать программу,  которая строит график параметрической функции на delphi.

Функция

```
x = cos (t) sin (at);

y = sin (t) cos (bt);

Тн =< t= <Tk и изменяет с шагом Th
```

Я написал код:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);

var x, y, xa, xb, t:real;

begin

 xa:= strToFloat(edit1.Text);

 xb:= strToFloat(edit2.Text);

 t:= strToFloat(edit3.Text);

 chart1.Series[0].Clear;

 x:= xa;

repeat

  y:=sin(x)*cos(xa);

  chart1.Series[0].AddY(y);

  x:= x+t;

  x:=cos(y)*sin(xb);

  chart1.Series[0].AddY(y);

  y:=xb;

until x>=xb or y>=xb;

end;

end.
```

Вопросы:

1. У меня выдаёт ошибку expected end but received "ожидаемый конец, но получил", выдаёт именно в `"until x>=xb or y>=xb;"`.
2. Правильно ли я написал программу (полностью)?

Comment: 1) отформатируйте код,Ю для этого есть специальная кнопка
2) 
 
>У меня выдаёт ошибку expected end but received "ожидаемый конец, но получил"

Уж лучше б вы не переводили

Comment: @Igor_bogun, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Скобки надо поставить `until (x>=xb) or (y>=xb);`, но это не спасет от отрицательного ответа на второй вопрос.

**Обновление**

[[@Igor_bogun](/users/24225/igor_bogun)](/users/24225/igor_bogun), Не совсем понятно задание. Нужно вывести график двух функций x и y или это так описано параметрическое вычисление координат x, y? В любом случае цикл у вас должен быть по t, которая изменяется от Tн до Tк с шагом Th, на каждом шаге вычисляя x и y. И чтоб добавить точку на график, надо пользоваться методом TLineSeries.addXY, а не addY.

Например, график параболы будет выглядеть так:

```
for i:=(-30) to 30 do
  Series1.AddXY(i, i*i);
```

Попробуйте сначала построить аналогичный график (со своими граничными условиями), после отладки легче будет решить вашу исходную задачу.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov спасибо за подсказку со скобками. Можно подсказку о правильности написания программы. Например: операторные скобки и т.д.

Comment: Обновил овтет

Comment: @Yura Ivanov Спасибо, обязательно попробую.